# How to store dates in a table

Tags: mysql, database, calendar

I am working on a project similar to Google calendar. To create it I am using ASP.NET. I would like users to have the ability to populate their own calendar entries, and then to crosscheck against other users calendar entries in order to check ideal times that meetings can be made.

I'm not sure what would be the best way to represent this in a database, however.

I have a table for users storing their name, id, password. I understand this and why/how to create it.

So I want to have a table for a users calendar - thinking about it, I would guess that the best way to do this would be to have one table consisting of the users id - but then what represents every hour of the users day? If I want to populate a database for, let's say, 3 years in advance of todays day. It is not practical to query a single database with a primary key identifying the user and a separate column for every day or even hour (let alone 15 minutes!).

What is the best way to do this? If you need elaboration please ask, I have tried to explain the problem as clearly as I can, but it is difficult not to be a tad ambiguous when discussing such a complex problem.

Comment: Also, as a sidenote, how does Google Calendar handle this?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to populate database with empty calendar entries. Why dont you just create a record in database when there is an event and when theres not then there is no record in DB?

Comment: Ok, just been running this over in my head and came across a simple problem. If I have a database of a million users, each of whom has 10 events, then that's 10 million events to search through in the one table. They will have a foreign key identifying the user, but wouldn't this be quite inefficient?

Comment: a-ha! For that there are indexes :) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would only store events, stored by their start and end (or start and duration).  You fill in the table of time slots programmatically.  Day/times that don't have an event overlapping them are empty.

Comment: I genuinely feel so incredibly slow! Thank you very much for this! :) So in my database I would have a primary key identifying the user, a date, a start time and an end time. I cross check against that and anything else is free! So simple!